# How can I deploy a Spring Boot REST API to BanaHost cPanel?

Tags: spring-boot, cpanel

I created a full stack application (Angular front end, java spring boot back end, mysql database), and I was able to upload successfully both the angular files and mysql into BanaHost cPanel, however I have not found useful information on how to upload spring boot REST API, as a consequence only the front end is working. How can I deploy this REST API on cpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot Applications can't just upload and deploy if you're utilizing a cPanel Web hosting (shared) plan, like you deployed the Angular Application by uploading.

For spring boot you must do it yourself, a Virtual Private Server or Dedicated Server will unlock the site hosting restriction. If you are not much familiar with the Linux command line, you can use a Window VPS instead. Providers like, Digital Ocean, Linode, and Oracle Cloud all provide free trials.

And also, there are platforms, such as Heroku (Platform as a Service(PaSS)), where you can deploy your app without the need for a VPS. You can refer their documentation regarding this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku

Comment: Hi Chandimal Adikari, I ended up getting a VPS service with BanaHosting, however I encountered the same issue, the Angular front end is working but the spring boot backend (jar file) is not doing anything. As I mentioned before I generated a jar file which I uploaded into file manager in VPS. Is this the correct process to successfully deploy a spring boot rest API which is consumed by an Angular application?

Comment: Just Uploading the jar file will not work. You have to go to the terminal of the VPS and run it. You can use `java -jar <path-to-your-jar-file>` to run it. If it works, you can run jar file as background task by adding suffix " &" to the above command.

Comment: This is the right method to run the java jar file from a vps terminal. I am getting an exception when running the jar file from putty via ssh but the fact that I am getting this exception means that the method to run it it's ok.